# How can I find out the opener of an GitHub PR in Jenkins (through CLI)?

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, pull-request

I would like to know, who (name, user, email) opened a GitHub pull-request in my Jenkins-Pipeline.
I saw, that there is already a plugin (https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin), but I'm not sure, if it provides this information.
So is there a way to get this info e.g. through the git-cli? Or how would you do it?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

[Pipeline GitHub plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-github-plugin) gives you a global `pullRequest` object that you can examine.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                if (env.CHANGE_ID) { // otherwise the object is not defined
                    println pullRequest.createdBy()
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with the Git CLI because pull requests are a feature of Github, not a feature of Git.

Two options:

1) Use the Github API: https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#get-a-single-pull-request

2) Use the CLI called `Hub`, like so:

```
hub pr show {PR-NUMBER-GOES-HERE} -f "%au"
```

see the documentation here: https://hub.github.com/hub-pr.1.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works flawlessly and is exactly what I was looking for.